# Двумерный массив Object[][] в Parcelable

Tags: java, android

Нужно запихнуть в `Parcelable` двумерный массив объектов `Object`. Пытаюсь это сделать так, но что-то не очень получается. Где может быть ошибка?

```
public class ObjectMatrix implements Parcelable {

    private Object[][] objects;

    public ObjectMatrix(Object[][] objs) {
        objects = objs;
    }

    private ObjectMatrix(Parcel in) {
        final int length = in.readInt();
        Object[][] arr = new Object[length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.readArray(Object[].class.getClassLoader());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        final int length = objects.length;
        dest.writeInt(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dest.writeArray(objects[i]);
        }
    }

    public static final Creator<ObjectMatrix> CREATOR = new Creator<ObjectMatrix>() {
        @Override
        public ObjectMatrix createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ObjectMatrix(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectMatrix[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ObjectMatrix[size];
        }
    };

    public Object[][] getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в конструкторе в локальную переменную всё сохраняется. Надо так:

```
private ObjectMatrix(Parcel in) {
    final int length = in.readInt();
    objects  = new Object[length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        objects [i] = in.readArray(Object[].class.getClassLoader());
    }
}
```